# Where to change default keyspace to use in Cassandra for Usergrid?

Tags: cassandra, usergrid

Where to change default keyspace to use in Cassandra for Usergrid?
What is the default keyspace used in Cassandra when I instal Usergrid? I can't find where to find the data stored via the admin portal.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  Are you on version 1.0 or 2.0?

The class for changing in 1.0 is here.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-usergrid/blob/master/stack/core/src/main/java/org/apache/usergrid/persistence/cassandra/CassandraService.java#L97

Version 2.0 is here

https://github.com/apache/incubator-usergrid/blob/two-dot-o/stack/core/src/main/java/org/apache/usergrid/persistence/cassandra/CassandraService.java#L93

It's not yet configurable, maybe open a ticket for it?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/USERGRID/